# Is there an easy way to create a string with SDL from a file?

Tags: c, string, file, sdl

Or is it better to go with common C functions?

Comment: what do you mean by create a string from file ? do you mean read a file ?

Comment: also, which SDL are we talking about here?

Comment: Yes. Open a file and make a string from the text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an I/O API in SDL, I'm not sure if it's any easier though, but it should be portable. Those are the relevant functions:

```
SDL_RWops *SDL_RWFromFile(const char *file, const char *mode); // open file
SDL_RWread(ctx, ptr, size, n); //read from file
SDL_RWclose(ctx)   //close file
```

There's an example [here](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_RWread) that shows how to open and read from a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL_rwops.h"
int main()
{
  int blocks;
  char buf[256];
  SDL_RWops *rw=SDL_RWFromFile("file.bin","rb");
  if(rw==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't open file.bin\n");
    return(1);
  }

  blocks=SDL_RWread(rw,buf,16,256/16);
  SDL_RWclose(rw);
  if(blocks<0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't read from file.bin\n");
    return(2);
  }

  fprintf(stderr,"Read %d 16-byte blocks\n",blocks);
  return(0);
}
```

Edit:There's a tutorial here on the file API, it may be easier to use when loading images:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/c-sharp/game-programming-using-sdl-the-file-io-api/

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what we're saving though there. Are there platforms that would benefit?

Comment: @LelaDax I think it can be used with the other API's, to load images or sound for example.

Comment: By the way, what would be the function to actually copy a string to a char*?

Comment: @LelaDax if you just want to read a string from file use something like `fgets` or `fscanf` if however, you'd like to load compressed images for example, then use the SDL I/O it should make it easier.

Comment: It is important to note that this API takes UTF-8 strings as a filename. So you can uniformly access files with any unicode characters in their names on all supported operating systems, a great advantage over the standard fopen API.